# Mongo: $match returns an empty array when is added to aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a query like this:

```
const data = await this.iveModel
      .aggregate([
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { $month: '$createdAt' },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
      ])
      .exec();
```

It works fine, but I want to limit the result to the current year, so I have added this:

```
const inicioDeAnio = moment()
      .startOf('year')
      .toISOString();

    const finDeAnio = moment()
      .endOf('year')
      .toISOString();

    const num = await this.iveModel
  .aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        createdAt: {
            $gt: inicioDeAnio,
            $lt: finDeAnio
        }
    }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { $month: '$createdAt' },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
      },
    },
  ])
  .exec();
```

And this always returns an empty array.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `inicioDeAnio` and `finDeAnio` variable is just string, if you want to query by date, you need to use **ISODate**. Something like:

```
...{
  $match: {
    createdAt: {
        $gt: ISODate(inicioDeAnio),
        $lt: ISODate(finDeAnio)
    }
}...
```

Comment: i did it with new Date and it worked. thank you so much!